# Google php api oauth 2.0 return uri

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to retrieve the email address of clients for a social login to my sites DB.

Implementation of the google+ quick-start app for PHP also includes some javascript which breaks IE8 and 9.

So I figured I'd look at a purely PHP API, and downloaded this from git-hub:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

I think I can feel my way using the example files to setting up the call for info I want, but have no idea how to get the result via the return uri. Infact when i run the examples, it logs in fine, and then calls the return uri of which when run doesn't contain any POST data, so I assume it uses some other method. I've google searched for a while now and no luck.

Does anyone have any examples, or point to any tutorials, or am I going down the wrong track?

Namaste

Answer (score 0):

The uri redirects to it's self same php file.
Use the `idtoken.php` example to gain the email address for your DB.

For testing:

Add the full address to your Google Developers Dashboard / Credentials / REDIRECT URIS:
`http://yoursite.com/google-api-php-client/examples/idtoken.php`

Edit the `idtoken.php` and fill out your `$client_id` and `$client_secret` and `$redirect_uri`

The `$redirect_uri` being:
`http://yoursite.com/google-api-php-client/examples/idtoken.php`

You'll see the result directly on the page, work it from there.